# Debugging node crashes in pm2

Tags: node.js, axios, pm2

I have an api that I built using node.js that serves my angular app. I am trying to deploy the api to my digital ocean droplet and run it with pm2. If I run the app directly against node it works just fine. However, when I make a certain api call while it is running with pm2 the app will crash. I have narrowed the crash down to an `axios` call. But other than that I can't figure out what is causing the crash and why it's only happening in pm2.

What would be the best way to figure out why it is crashing in pm2?

Comment: do you have ssh access to the remote machine? `pm2 log` would print the recent logs from the process. If you are using axios with await, just enclose it in `try ... catch` and print the caught exception to console. Stack trace should help in debugging.

Comment: Good call on the logs! My api pulls a file and saves it to the server. Since I have pm2 watching for changes it restarts once the file is saved. Is there a way to have pm2 ignore changes in certain directories?

Comment: Yeah, you can do that. Check the `ignore_watch` field available for use in application configuration here: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/#advanced-features. EDIT: same option is also available with `--ignore-watch` cli switch, in case you are not using config files yet.

Comment: Perfect! I defined a process.json file to start the api and it is working now. Thanks so much for the help!